# XmlSerializer not populating sub-elements

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I've used XSD.EXE to convert an XSD into an object.  That works fine and I can Deserialize using XMLSerializer just fine, except that the subelements which are generated as arrays don't populate.

```
    private SubElements[] subelementsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("SubElement", IsNullable=false)]
    public SubElement[] SubElement {
        get {
            return this.subelementField;
        }
        set {
            this.subelementField = value;
        }
    }
```

Even though there is data in the XML it just doesn't populate it when I use the following code:

```
// Deserialize
var result = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(data.XMLText.ToString()));
```

The root elements all work fine, just not the sub elements of this type of XML data:

```
<RootNode Weight="205" Year="1995">
  <ParentNodeWhichWorksFine Contact="John Doe">
    <SubElement SomeAttribute="123">
      <Location>New York City</Location>
      <Team>New York Pizza</Team>
    </SubElement>
  </ParentNodeWhichWorksFine>
</RootNode>
```

Am I missing some hints or something else that XSD.EXE is not including?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlArrayItemAttribute` attribute specifies a name for the *child nodes* of the array element defined by the public member `SubElements`. So that sample xml doesn't conform to the xsd, if that's the exact generated class xsd.exe produced.

According to the generated class, the `<SubElement>` items should be contained in a parent `<SubElements>` node like this:

```
<RootNode Weight="205" Year="1995">
  <ParentNodeWhichWorksFine Contact="John Doe">
    <SubElements>
      <SubElement SomeAttribute="123">
        <Location>New York City</Location>
        <Team>New York Pizza</Team>
      </SubElement>
    </SubElements>
  </ParentNodeWhichWorksFine>
</RootNode>
```

If you have control over the schema, I think changing it so that it corresponds to the sample xml is preferable (no parent node, following [Pavel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645955/xmlserializer-not-populating-sub-elements/1646002#1646002)), since the parent array nodes are superfluous.

Comment: Turned out that a tag was not being included in the source XML (SubElements).  thanks alow.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the class within which you define property `SubElement` is the one corresponding to `ParentNodeWhichWorksFine`? If so, try this change:

```
[XmlElement("SubElement", IsNullable=false)]
public SubElement[] SubElement
```

Also, you say that you've generated this code using xsd.exe. What was the input in that case - an .xsd file? If so, can you post the relevant part of it, too?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your SubElement array in your generated class is missing the [XmlArray] attribute.

It needs to look like this:

`[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("SubElements")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("SubElement", IsNullable=false)]
public SubElement[] SubElement {
}`

Something is not quite right in your XSD file, I reckon.